# Is it possible to capture the bandit leaders?

Tags: mods, mount-and-blade-warband

Several times now, I've engaged one of the bandit leaders and his large swarm of bandits but they've escaped every single time.  I'm wondering if its possible to capture them at all since they don't belong to any kingdom.  This is with the Floris mod.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to capture them? Maybe you are just unlucky.

Comment: @lyrion I don't know.  Maybe it's because they dont belong to any kingdoms so no one might ransom them.  Or like you said I could be unlucky out of around 10 tries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the TaleWorlds Floris forums:

> The bandit leaders are never captured - they always escape after the battle. After a week or so in-game, they respawn again with followers.

I've defeated bandit leaders about 5 times in battle and never captured one.

source:

http://forums.taleworlds.com/index.php?topic=237444.0

Comment: damn, well that's lame.  Oh and welcome.